# PHP Split column when item = 4

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, arrays

I have an array and now I'm putting this array into `for loop` to show each item in this array, but I want set item limit (4 item each column), here is my code.

```
<?php 
    $area = $custom_area_settings; //is an array with 5 element
    for($i=0;$i<=count($area->custom_area_list) - 1; $i++):
        if($area->custom_area_list[$i]->top_show):
            echo '<div class="sub-column column'.$i.'">';
            echo '<p class="line"> ' . $area->custom_area_list[$i]->header . '</p>';
            echo '</div>';
        endif;
    endfor;
?>
```

On this code, div `column$i` had created each time loop ran but I just want this div create when loop run 4 times, after 4 times this div will create again, after 8 times this div will create again and continue...

Here is the result I want.

```
Column 1           Column 2
---------------    ---------------
item 1             item 5
item 2             item 6
item 3             item 7
item 4             item 8
```

Here is the result I'm getting now

```
Column 1
---------------------
item 1
Column 2
---------------------
item 2
.....
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $area = $custom_area_settings; //is an array with 5 element
    $i=0;
    echo '<div class="sub-column column'.$i.'">';
    for($i=0;$i<=count($area->custom_area_list) - 1; $i++):
        if($area->custom_area_list[$i]->top_show):
            if($i%4 === 0):
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div class="sub-column column'.$i.'">';
            endif;
            echo '<p class="line"> ' . $area->custom_area_list[$i]->header . '</p>';
        endif;
    endfor;
    echo '</div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Updated:**

```
$html = $i%4 === 0 ? '<div class="sub-column column'
                     . $i . '">' 
                     . '{1}' . '</div>' : '{1}';

echo strtr($html,array('{1}' => '<p class="line"> '
                              . $area->custom_area_list[$i]->header
                              . '</p>'
          ));
```

**%** divides **$i by 4** and returns the remainder which must be equal to **0** in this case

Comment: Would be nice to explain this.  Basically within that if block, you close your previous DIV if one exists, and open a new one.  The if block goes within the for block, at the top.

Comment: I try this but each column only show 1 item, please help,

 if($i%4===0):
  echo '<div class="sub-column column'.$i.'">';
  echo '<p class="line"> ' . $area->custom_area_list[$i]->header . '</p>';
  echo '</div>';
 endif;

:(

Comment: Vote +1, I'll follow this way to find the solutions, thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use the `array_chunk` command

**Example**

```
$chunkedArray = array_chunk(['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five'], 4);

echo '<div class="row">';
array_walk( $chunkedArray, function($array) 
{
    echo '<div class="col-md-4">'          
    foreach( $array as $key => $value )
    {
        echo "<p class='line'>$value</p>";
    }
    echo '</div>';
});
echo '</div>';
```

This example was created using twitter bootstrap css classes.  I'm sure it could be optimized, just showcasing the array_chunk approach.